# UITableview not reloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have a `tableview` loading properly for the first time, but it should reload the data when I'm calling the method `loadJsonData`. The `reloadData` method is called at the end of the `loadJsonData` method. But the `tableview` is not reloading. The data source is updated before calling the `reloadData` method. The delegate and dataSource of `tableview` are also set to self.

I checked if it is executing `numberOfRowsInSection` method and found that it is not executing the method. Can anybody help me?

Below is the code:

```
-(void)loadJsonData:(NSString *)fileName:(int )count
 {

    titleArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dateArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    descriptionArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    urlArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    thumbnailArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"json"];


    NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];



    SBJSON *Parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [Parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];

    NSArray *items=[data objectForKey:fileName];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                                  ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    items=sortedArray;



    for (NSDictionary *item in items)
    {   

        NSString *temp=[item objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString* str = [temp stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [titleArray addObject:str];

        temp=[item objectForKey:@"date"];
        [dateArray addObject:temp];

        temp=[item objectForKey:@"thumbnailURL"];
        str = [temp stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [thumbnailArray addObject:str];
        temp=[item objectForKey:@"description"];
        str = [temp stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [descriptionArray addObject:str];
        temp=[item objectForKey:@"htmlURL"];
        str = [temp stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [urlArray addObject:str];

    }
    [Parser release];


    if (count==1)
    {
        [tableview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        NSLog(@"reload data test");

    }


}



  -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"nof rows test..");
    return [thumbnailArray count];
}
```

EDIT

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell;
    cell=(CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];



        cell.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        cell.Title.text=[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell.description.text=[descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[thumbnailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        cell.Image.image=img;
        cell.Date.text=[dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"date is :  %@",cell.Date.text);             

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Verify that datasource and delegate has set properly or not.

Comment: In the interface Builder datasource and delegate are connected to files owner.

Comment: Also verify thubnailArray and post the code of - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.

Comment: I have verified the thumbnailArray also.It's updating properly.

Comment: I'm adding the cellForRowAtIndexPath method also.

Comment: Check it with my given modified code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the number of section first. If for some reason your code returns 0, none of the other delegate functions will be called.

Comment: Thnx a lot boss :)
I have tried everything, but this only works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following.

```
if (count > 0)
{
    [tableview reloadData];
    NSLog(@"reload data test");

}
```

Comment: Thank You for your Response."count" is actually a parameter that is passed to the "loadJsonData" method.It's not actually representing the datasource count.Anyway,it is executing that condition and I'm able to see "reload data test" in the console.Sorry for the poor naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but feel that your `performSelectorOnMainThread:` is a little redundant and *may* be causing your problem, though I can't see why. Could you not just use: `[tableview reloadData];`

The answer provided my @iPhoneiPadDev points out the flaw I missed. Change your if to `if (count >= 0)`

Comment: I have tried [tableview reloadData] also.Still not reloading.The count value will be either 0 or 1.I want to reload if count value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as given below...

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell;
    cell=(CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
    }

    cell.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.Title.text=[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.description.text=[descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[thumbnailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    cell.Image.image=img;
    cell.Date.text=[dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"date is :  %@",cell.Date.text);             

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. I modified it ...still not working.In my code, "numberOfRowsInSection" method is not executing.Hence if I'm not mistaken, I think that "reloadData" method is not getting executed.

Answer (score -1):

99.99% the problem is only related to settings `delagate` and `dataSource` for `tableview` (or you might not have saved the xib if you are setting them from xib) if the `numberOfRowsInSection` is not being Invoked.

remove all delegates. reassign delegates and ensure you are saving all your files including xib.